# Regression imputation with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, imputation

I want to do **regression imputation** with **dplyr** in R *efficiently*. Here is my problem: I have a data set with many **missing values** for one column - let's call it `p`. Now I want to estimate the missing values of `p` with a regression imputation approach. For that I regress `p` on a set of variables with **OLS** using uncensored data (a subset of the data set without missing values for `p`). Then I use the estimated coefficients to calculate the missing values of `p`.

My data set looks like that:

```
df = data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  group = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2),
  sub_group = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  p = c(4.3, 5.7, NA, NA, NA, 10),
  var1 = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2),
  var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

where `id` represent individuals, which buy goods from a `group` (e.g. "food") with `subgroups` (like "bread"). `p` is the price, while `var1` and `var2` are some demographic variables (like "education" and "age").

What I've done so far:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- as_tibble(df)

# Create uncensored data
uncensored_df <- df %>%
filter(!is.na(p))

# Run regression on uncensored data
imp_model <- lm(p ~ var1 + var2, data = uncensored_df)

# Get the coefficients of the fitted model
coefs <- unname(imp_model$coefficients)

# Use coefficients to compute missing values of p
censored_df <-df %>%
filter(is.na(p)) %>%
group_by(id, group, sub_group) %>%
  mutate(p = coefs[1] + coefs[2] * var1 + coefs[3] * var2)  

# And finally combine the two subsets                                 
bind_rows(uncensored_df, censored_df) %>% arrange(id, group, sub_group)
```

As I use more than `var1` and `var2` in my actual problem (about 30 variables), what is a better way to do regression imputation with dplyr? (I'm also open for non-dplyr solutions, though.)

Comment: Have you looked at the [`mice`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.13.0/topics/mice) package?

Comment: I didn't know of that package. I'll check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

fit <- lm(p ~ ., data = select(df, p, starts_with("var")))


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(p = ifelse(is.na(p), predict(fit, newdata = across()), p)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

**How it works**

- For starters, when fitting your model, you can subset your data frame using `select` and any of the [tidyselect](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/) helpers to select your dependent variables (here used `starts_with("var")`). This subset data frame then allows you to use the `~ .` notation which means regress `p` on everything in the subset data frame.
- Next you create a row-wise data frame and use your model to predict where `p` is missing. In this instance `across` turns each row into a 1x6 tibble that you can pass to the `newdata` argument. `predict` then uses the model fit and this new data to predict a value of `p`.

**Output**

```
     id group sub_group     p  var1  var2
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1         1  4.3    0.3     0
2     1     1         2  5.7    0.1     0
3     1     2         3  3.60   0.4     0
4     2     1         1  5.10   0.9     1
5     2     1         2 10.7    0.1     1
6     2     2         3 10      0.2     1
```

---

**Benchmarking**

As mentioned in the comments, for large data frames the rowwise operation takes significantly longer than some other options:

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- df %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1E5, replace = T)

fit <- lm(p ~ ., data = select(df1, p, starts_with("var")))


dplyr_rowwise <- function(){
  df1 %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(p = ifelse(is.na(p), predict(fit, newdata = across()), p)) %>% 
    ungroup()
}

dplyr_coalesce <- function(){
  df1 %>%
    mutate(p = coalesce(p, predict(fit, newdata = df1)))
}

base_index <- function(){
  isna <- is.na(df1$p)
  df1$p[isna] <- predict(fit, newdata = subset(df1, isna))
}

microbenchmark(
  dplyr_rowwise(),
  dplyr_coalesce(),
  base_index(),
  times = 10L
)

Unit: milliseconds
             expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq  
  dplyr_rowwise() 63739.9512 64441.0800 66926.46041 65513.51785 66923.0241
 dplyr_coalesce()     6.5901     6.9037     8.55971     7.21125     7.7157
     base_index()    13.0368    13.1790    15.73682    13.53310    19.3004
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. However, for large data sets with a lot of rows the row-wise operations are computationally demanding. Maybe I should try one of the packages designed for imputation.

Comment: @timm that's right. I've updated my answer with some benchmarking and other, faster options.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. This is really helpful.